# Why is my code is so slow to execute in R?

Tags: r

Please, I have a dataframe, which contains a list of products.

For each product, I do an extrapolation to find missing values (the a column must be a list between **1 and 20**).

Then, I also verify, if a certain value in a was duplicated many times, so I create a new column to put the count on it.

At the end, each product will have only one line, with 20 columns of b, and 20 columns of the count of redundance of each class

The code is up and running however, it is so **long to execute**:

Similar data:

```r
a<-c(1, 3, 4, 8.7, 8.7, 9, 10, 12, 19.3, 20,5, 7, 8, 9, 9.1, 11, 11, 11, 12, 14)
b<-c(10, 30, 40, 60, 87, 90, 100, 120, 190, 200,8, 3, 5, 60, 87, 90, 130, 120, 190, 200)
prod_id<-c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)
df<-data.frame(a=a, b=b, prod=prod_id)
```

Manipulations:

```r
  df_result<- data.frame()
prods<- dplyr::distinct(df,prod_id)$prod_id #Distinct Prod_ID
for(j in 1:NROW(prods)) {
  dfj<- filter(df, prod_id==prods[j]) 
  sdf<-as.data.frame(Hmisc::approxExtrap(dfj$a, dfj$b, xout = c(1:20))) #Extrapolating
  sdf$z<-stack(pmax(table(factor(as.integer(dfj$a), levels = 1:20)), 1))[2:1]$values - 1 #Increment if a value was there more than 1 time
  sdf<-select_(sdf,"y","z") 
  sdf<-as.data.frame(t(unlist(sdf))) 
  df_result<-rbind(df_result,sdf)
  
}
```

The result is as follows

```
> df_result
  y1   y2 y3   y4       y5       y6       y7       y8 y9       y10 y11 y12     y13      y14      y15      y16      y17      y18      y19 y20 z1 z2 z3 z4 z5 z6
1 10 20.0 30 40.0 44.25532 48.51064 52.76596 57.02128 90 100.00000 110 120 129.589 139.1781 148.7671 158.3562 167.9452 177.5342 187.1233 200  0  0  0  0  0  0
2 18 15.5 13 10.5  8.00000  5.50000  3.00000  5.00000 60  88.42105  90 190 195.000 200.0000 205.0000 210.0000 215.0000 220.0000 225.0000 230  0  0  0  0  0  0
  z7 z8 z9 z10 z11 z12 z13 z14 z15 z16 z17 z18 z19 z20
1  0  1  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2  0  0  1   0   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: Your whole example benchmarks at 11ms on my (very slow) work computer. What size is the data frame you are using?

Comment: I have millions of products, so it takes quite long to execute

Comment: What is this supposed to return `dplyr::distinct(df,prod_id)$prod_id`?

Comment: i think it is just the `unique()` values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a **new** solution with `data.table`:

```
  dt <- as.data.table(df)

  do_stuff <- function(a, b) {
    sdf <- Hmisc::approxExtrap(a, b, xout = c(1:20))
    sdf$z <- stack(pmax(table(factor(as.integer(a), levels = 1:20)), 1))$values - 1
    sdf <- as.data.frame(t(unlist(sdf[c("y", "z")]))) 
    sdf
  }

  df_result <- dt[, do_stuff(a, b), by = prod_id]
```

And a benchmark with the **original**:

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

microbenchmark(
"original" = {
  df_result <- data.frame()
  prods<- dplyr::distinct(df,prod_id)$prod_id #Distinct Prod_ID
  for(j in 1:NROW(prods)) {
    dfj<- filter(df, prod_id==prods[j]) 
    sdf<-as.data.frame(Hmisc::approxExtrap(dfj$a, dfj$b, xout = c(1:20))) #Extrapolating
    sdf$z<-stack(pmax(table(factor(as.integer(dfj$a), levels = 1:20)), 1))[2:1]$values - 1 #Increment if a value was there more than 1 time
    sdf<-select_(sdf,"y","z") 
    sdf<-as.data.frame(t(unlist(sdf))) 
    df_result<-rbind(df_result,sdf)
  }
},
"new" = {
  dt <- as.data.table(df)

  do_stuff <- function(a, b) {
    sdf <- Hmisc::approxExtrap(a, b, xout = c(1:20))
    sdf$z <- stack(pmax(table(factor(as.integer(a), levels = 1:20)), 1))$values - 1
    sdf <- as.data.frame(t(unlist(sdf[c("y", "z")]))) 
    sdf
  }

  df_result <- dt[, do_stuff(a, b), by = prod_id]
}
)
```

**Results:**

```
Unit: milliseconds
     expr       min        lq     mean    median        uq       max neval
 original 20.090200 20.841403 22.63290 21.705137 23.479769 32.535576   100
      new  2.063369  2.279269  2.61532  2.411447  2.538806  9.312241   100
```

Comment: I assume, that there is maybe more to optimise wihtin the `do_stuff()` function, but factor 10 is a start.

Comment: I tried to optimise this without using data.table, but the result still took twice as long as yours. I deleted my answer when I saw this!